# Access $_POST data after redirect

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

How can I access `$_POST` data after a page redirect?

I guess there is some way to tell WordPress to pass all `$_POST` data to the redirected address, like it does with `$_GET` data, using Rewrite Rules, but how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redirects are GET requests usually, and the browser doesn’t send the POST data for those. That’s not something WordPress can change.

You could create a session, or – better – process the POST data first, *then* redirect. In your plugin, you could do:

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'process_post_data', 0 );

function process_post_data()
{
    // Read raw POST data, not touched by WordPress
    $data = file_get_contents( 'php://input' );

    // then redirect
}
```

Comment: That's fine, where I can hook a function to get the $_POST data in Wordpress before redirect?

Comment: @Archedius See my update.

Comment: That answers my question. It doesn't work with Rewrite Rules though, I have to analyze the URL without rewriting then redirect at Template Redirect, I think.

Comment: @Archedius Internal redirect (no URL change) are fine. Redirects for the browser (to a new URL) should come after POST data processing.